# If I born as male in this life can my soul transmigrate and became female in next life?

Tags: atma, rebirth

I have this question in my mind since when I knew about soul, can a person who is male and his soul in next life can be female?

I hope its pretty clear, if not please let me know. My english might not be perfect. I will try to explain.

Comment: Are you asking about soul being male or female or taking male in one birth and female in another birth?

Comment: I am trying to understand both the things here. But primary objective is, taking male in one birth and female in another birth.

Comment: yes, definitely. why only woman, we can even be born as deva, or donkey in next birth. all depends on previous karma + present karma.